# Excel Vba, How to change cell value with another cell?

Tags: excel, vba, text, multiple-columns, contains

```
A COLUMN                    B COLUMN                 NEW A COLUMN (A -> NEW A)
MN3312 XP XMR123 X123KV     XP XMR123 X123KV         XP XMR123 X123KV
IX3122 JM EMB105B MVLF      JM EMB105B MVLF          JM EMB105B MVLF
X891230 ME ROMD2111MD       ME ROMD2111MD            ME ROMD2111MD
P305875 LKX 81230 R123 KV   LKX 81230 R123 KV        LKX 81230 R123 KV
PL0123 28-8JMZKWI123NK      28-8JMZKWI123NK          28-8JMZKWI123NK
OXP8482 BKG 143 NKM KLP     BKG 143 NKM KLP          BKG 143 NKM KLP
Q309650 309 01DIQL ZBNQL    309 01DIQL ZBNQL         309 01DIQL ZBNQL
```

If the cell' value of A Column contains the cell's value of B Column, the cell's value of A column change to the cell's value of B column.

Could you figure it out by code that problem??...

AIM: the cell's value of A Column change to the cell's value of B Column
(If contains the value of B column)
And, I want to make use of "for -next"!

please, help me to make it!

Answer (score 2):

Heavily commented so you know what is going on :) Just side scroll to see it.

You will need to define some of the variables to make this work correctly. I have put everything you need to change in one place.

```
Sub searchSegment()
' loops through all cells in column A, compare segements of cell string to column B, and if found replace column A with column B data

    ' declare variable types - immutable                                    do not modify
    Dim originWB As Workbook                                                ' origin workbook       - full name of the file containing data to be searched.
    Dim originWS As Worksheet                                               ' origin worksheet      - worksheet within origin workbook containing data to be searched.
    Dim searchWB As Workbook                                                ' search workbook       - full name of the file containing data to use as a search.
    Dim searchWS As Worksheet                                               ' search worksheet      - worksheet within search workbook containing data to use as a search.
    Dim originCol As String                                                 ' origin column         - column containing data to be searched.
    Dim searchCol As String                                                 ' search column         - column containing data to use as a search.
    Dim hdrStatus As Integer                                                ' header status         - define if top row contains header or data.
    Dim searchSegSize As Integer                                            ' search segment size   - consequtive characters making up the search segment.
    Dim searchSeg As String                                                 ' search segment        - piece of data checked against string. not constant / user defined.
    Dim i, j, n As Long                                                     ' loop variables        - used to iterate through loops. not user defined.
    Dim lRow As Long                                                        ' last row              - last row with data found in the origin column. not constant / user defined.
    Dim originRng As Range                                                  ' origin range          - varying location containing string to be searched. not constant / user defined.
    Dim searchRng As Range                                                  ' search range          - varying location containing search string. not constant / user defined.

    ' variables - mutable                                                   ok to modify
    Set originWB = Workbooks("SO.xlsm")                                     ' set the name of the origin workbook here
    Set originWS = originWB.Worksheets("Summary")                           ' set the name of the origin worksheet here
    Set searchWB = Workbooks("SO.xlsm")                                     ' set the name of the search workbook here
    Set searchWS = searchWB.Worksheets("Summary")                           ' set the name of the search worksheet here
    hdrStatus = 0                                                           ' 0 = no header, 1 = header
    searchSegSize = 4                                                       ' set number of characters in the search segment
    originCol = "A"                                                         ' set column of data being searched
    searchCol = "B"                                                         ' set column of data used as a search
    
    ' code - immutable                                                      do not modify
    lRow = originWS.Cells(originWS.Rows.Count, originCol).End(xlUp).Row     ' find the last row in originCol of the originWS object
    
    For i = (header + 1) To lRow                                            ' creates a For loop and declares i as each iteration (i = 1 then i = 2, etc)
        Set originRng = originWS.Range(originCol & i)                       ' sets varying range to locate string to be searched
        Set searchRng = originWS.Range(searchCol & i)                       ' sets varying range to locate string to be used as a search
        j = Round(Len(originRng), 0)                                        ' defines number of iterations for second (nested) loop
        For n = 1 To lRow                                                   ' second For loop to search string in x character segments. searchSegSize defined by user.
            If n = 1 Then                                                   ' first iteration starts searching string from character 1
                searchSeg = Mid(originRng, 1, searchSegSize)                ' define what to search for if iteration = 1
            Else
                searchSeg = Mid(originRng, 1 + n, searchSegSize)            ' define what to search for if iteration > 1
            End If
            If Len(searchSeg) < searchSegSize Then Exit For                 ' stop if the search segement is smaller than searchSegSize
            If InStr(1, originRng, searchSeg) > 0 Then                      ' if search segment is found then
                originRng.Value = searchRng.Value                           ' replace originCol with newly found data
                Exit For                                                    ' stop as action has been taken
            End If
        Next                                                                ' iterate to next search segment (nested loop)
    Next                                                                    ' iterate to next cell within defined range for primary loop
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks alot!

but the thing is that the cells of B column is positioned in anothersheet, how do i figure it out??...

Comment: @NAVER.YSWOO I've added a second workbook/worksheet reference in there for you. No need to figure it out :) if you have questions, feel free to ask

Comment: It was my pleasure :)

Comment: @NAVER.YSWOO Be sure to mark this as the answer / upvote if you can :)