# Matching substrings in a column of data using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have column of data as shown in the screenshot. What I need is to find the matching sub-strings on it and spit it out in the 2nd column. The search algorithm should start from the longest match to the shortest match and it would need to compare each string to itself from the column (sounds difficult for me). Then for the 3rd column, the algorithm should spit out the unique characters (those that it did not find any match) searching from the longest character to the shortest one too.

I am not trying to get spoon fed on this but I just really don't know where to start. Its a bit difficult algorithm I suppose, something that requires pattern recognition. I would be very happy if you can help me how to start it out (if not provide the code to me). I know some basic level VBA coding but I would very glad if you can help me how to start it.

PS: I already have a script that finds and replaces the first column from a table of data but here, I would want to make it reverse. Since the naming convention of the tags differs for each file, I want an algorithm that do the opposite, where I can generate a set of table from the similar characters in a column of data then create my dictionary from there and run my Find and replace to this data I have.

Thanks a lot!

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Your data seems to be the same until the word `HAMILTON.` then it changes. You want everything before that in column B and everything after that in column C?

Comment: Hi! For this set of data it just appears to be the same, but for my other set of data, those first characters differs. So its no a straightforward algorithm that gets those substring before hamilton (which are all common) then spit out the varying strings on the third column. Actually I found this problem to be a classic computer science problem as shown in this wikipedia link but I just don't know how to put this in VBA code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem.

Comment: I've created something that you could use to search the data in quadrants: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63590515/4101210

Comment: Hi @Mech thanks a lot! I will try this out to fine tune my find and replace code but so far it works fine. What I actually need is a code that find similar substrings from the set of data in the first column without comparing it to another set of data. So its like finding the common characters among itself without a predefined table to look for. Thanks